How to set background colour in android compose when drawBehind is used on modifier
part of my android jetpack compose application displays a list of items with a colour coded arc as shown below:-
Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(Dimen.padding_m)
            .background(color = if (selectedModuleId == module.id) MyColors.secondaryLight else Color.Transparent)
            .drawBehind {
                drawArc(
                    color = Color(module.parsedColor),
                    startAngle = 225f,
                    sweepAngle = 260f,
                    useCenter = false,
                    topLeft = Offset(-80f, 0f),
                    size = Size(80f, size.height)
                )
            }
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .clickable { onSelected(module) }
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )

this all works fine apart from when each list item is selected the background doesnt change for the "drawBehind" content.
e.g. .background(color = if (selectedModuleId == module.id) MyColors.secondaryLight else Color.Transparent) this code doesnt affect the drawArc background.
how can i change the background colour for the arc being drawn in the drawBehind block?

The drawBehind modifier is applied after the background color is drawn. Therefore, changing the background color using the background modifier won't affect the color of the arc drawn using drawBehind. Use the drawWithContent modifier. The drawWithContent modifier allows you to draw custom content while preserving the original background color.
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(Dimen.padding_m)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .clickable { onSelected(module) }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .drawWithContent {
            // Draw the background color
            drawRect(
                color = if (selectedModuleId == module.id) MyColors.secondaryLight else Color.Transparent
            )
            // Draw the arc
            drawBehind {
                drawArc(
                    color = Color(module.parsedColor),
                    startAngle = 225f,
                    sweepAngle = 260f,
                    useCenter = false,
                    topLeft = Offset(-80f, 0f),
                    size = Size(80f, size.height)
                )
            }
            // Draw the content
            drawContent()
        }
)

